# First public template. What to do?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css

I'm on my way to create a `"open source"` free template, and the only requirement for this is that they MUST keep my name at the buttom of the template.

And that's why i'm here! How can i make sure a user keeps my name at the bottom? I know that you can create something so you can delete the code, but i'm not sure how to do that, and even if it is legal.

What should i do in this situation?
It's codede in html/css/javascript/jquery/mvc/c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's **Open Source**, then anybody have access to the code and can change the deletion code or credits., thus, there isn't really nothing you can do to defend the credits at the bottom, except to hope the appropriate license you're publish your code under will protect you.

**More on License:**

1. http://choosealicense.com/
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883638/how-to-publish-code-as-open-source

Comment: Can't i copyright it or something? :)

Comment: @UnScope, Added links.